# Laravel - problema listando objetos

Tags: laravel

mi duda es que tengo unos objetos que voy listando y tengo que hacer una comprobación con el objeto anterior y no se como localizarlo.
En concreto tengo una lista de eventos y quiero comprobar si el mes del evento anterior es el mismo que el del actual para no mostrarlo y asi poder agrupar los eventos por meses.
Esta es la funcion que tengo en el HomeController:

```
public function getDashboard()
{
    $eventos = Evento::where('admin','=', Auth::user()->id)
                        ->get();
    $data = array('eventos' => $eventos);
    return view('home', $data) ;
}
```

Y asi los muestro en la vista:

```
@if(isset($eventos) && count($eventos) > 0)
      @foreach ($eventos as $evento) 
         <!--
            si el mes y año del evento es igual que el anterior
            entonces
            no mostrar mes
         -->
          <div class="media pt-3 border-bottom">
              <div class="marco-fecha align-self-start mr-3">
                  <span class="d-block numero-dia">{{ $evento->obtenerFechaLarga()->format('d') }}</span>
                  <span class="d-block nombre-mes">{{ $evento->obtenerFechaLarga()->format('l') }}</span>
              </div>

              <div class="media-body">
                   <h5 class="mt-1">{{ $evento->title }}</h5>
              </div>
          </div>

      @endforeach
@endif
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿y cómo está almacenado el mes?

Comment: Seria bueno que publiques tu modelo para poder analizar mejor tu problema, quiza sea suficiente con un groupBy

Comment: el modelo es simplemento esto:<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Evento extends Model
{
    public function user()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User','admin');
 }

 public function obtenerFechaLarga()
 {
  $fecha   = array();
  $fecha = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->date);
  return $fecha;  
 }


}